# How Can I use dependent variables in Magento Email Templates

Tags: orders, email-templates, dependency

I would like to achieve the following in the New Order Email Template (Magento):

If (order amount > 300 EUR)
echo "some example text"
else
echo nothing

Any ideas on how I can achieve this the most simple way?

I noticed that Magento uses {{depend}} in the template, but I can't really figure out on how to solve my case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()`
What you need to change is the list of variables assigned to the template. So turn this :

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $this,
        'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
    )
);
```

Into this:

```
$customText = '';
if ($this->getBaseGrandTotal() > 300) {
    $customText = "Your 300E text here";
}
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $this,
        'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml, 
        'custom_text'  => $customText
    )
);
```

After doing this you can add in your e-mail template just this line in the place you want the text to appear

```
{{var custom_text}}
```